# Apply conditional formatting to a range of cell using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

This is my table:
[image: Sheet]

What I'm trying to do is to make a conditional formatting rule that will highlight Column-A (Studio).

Here is my formula: If Column-B (Weekend Gross) is greater than $500,000 and Column-C (Total Gross) is greater than $10,000,000. Column A will be formatted with red fill and dark red text.

[image: Formula]

[image: Movies sheet]

The rule will be applied to Movies(2) sheet. I tried a lot of formula but I do not know why it does not work. Please help me correct my error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Select `A2`. try this formula:

```
=AND(B2>500000,C2>10000000)
```

And use **Format Painter** (select `A2` and click Format painter then select column `A`)

[image: 1]